# Oracle APEX - Interactive Grid not rendering correctly in IE 11

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-18.2

I am currently using Oracle APEX version 18.2.0.00.12 on Internet Explorer 11 and I am experiencing problems with getting my interactive grids to render correctly with regards to the widths of the columns.

I created an Interactive Grid on my page with the following query:

SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME;

I did not change any of the default settings for the region; all I did was create the IG and then run the page.

When I run the page in IE, this is what I see:

[image]

Note: I have not yet added any data to the table.

The problem is that all of the columns are too narrow. However, when I run the same page in Google Chrome, this is what I see:

[image]

The columns are all sized proportionally in order to take up the full width of the IG, which is what I want.

I do not understand why the IG is rendered differently in IE versus Chrome. I know that I can set the Minimum Column Width for each column in the IG, but I would hate to do that every time I create an IG. Is there a different solution that would make the IG render in IE the same way that it does in Chrome?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Cross browser compatibility is a very old, very common problem.  I'm not familiar with the tools you mention, but it may be possible to fix if you can edit the CSS stylesheet (or add new styles through some other method such as a dashboard page).

Comment: IE has caused me much grief until we finally just decided to not support it. We have had this same issue(did not resolve it), but one more thing you should check if you will still support IE. IG with columns being LOVs. We never did figure out specifically which circumstances led to this, but sometimes you would pick one entry from the LOV and then when the LOV closed it wouldnt display your current selection, if you saved it would work, just not before. We had a range of LOVs, from shared components, static values, to SQL querys that returned LOVs from the database

Answer (score 0):

Actually remembered a solutuion. I cannot explain to you why this works, or how best to use it. But when I had this problem I sort of patched it by saving a default report.

But the strange thing, you had to manually adjust every column, even if it was to the same size as before, it just had to have been adjusted before the default report was saved. Then the grid would show as it should, but this isnt that good a solution since its only ok if everybody uses the same size display,..